# Using itertools to generate combinations from 2 lists

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have two lists `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`. I'd like to generate a list of all combinations as follows using `itertools`

`ResultingList = [[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6]]`

So far I've only investigated the `itertools.combinations` function which seems that it can only handle something like this:

```
list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6],2))
```

Which outputs an incorrect result. How can I generate `ResultingList` above?

Thanks

Comment: not really... this formulation of the question is much more straightforward and helpful imo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

*For general understaging:*

As stated in the docs, `product` is the equivalent of:
`((x,y) for x in A for y in B)` where A and B are your input lists

Comment: yup yup thanks. thats how you do it

Comment: And if you must have sublists: `list(map(list, product([1,2,3], [4,5,6])))`

Answer (score 2):

if you are not importing product from itertools , then you can use this way also

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[]
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        c.append((i,j))
print c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply :

```
print([(i,j) for i in a for j in b])
```

output:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```